# Validar datos guardados por el hash argon2i

Tags: php

Estoy guardando una simple contraseña con el hash argon2i

`$clave = password_hash($_POST['clave'], PASSWORD_ARGON2I);`

Lo que no entiendo es como volver a traer esos datos para validar la contraseña, yo se que

```
hash --> a contraseña no es posible
```

Pero como puedo hacer para que pueda validar los datos?

En la validacion solo tengo lo siguiente:

```
$sql = $objdatabase->prepare('SELECT id_usuario, cedula, nombre, apellido, usuario,agencias.nombre_tienda, rango.rango,aperturada,ayuda
        FROM usuarios INNER JOIN agencias ON usuarios.agencia=agencias.id_tienda
        INNER JOIN rango ON usuarios.rango=rango.id_rango 
        WHERE usuario =:usuario AND clave =:clave');
    //Definimos los parametros de la Query
    $sql->bindParam(':usuario', $_POST['usuario'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sql->bindParam(':clave', $_POST['clave'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    //Exjecutamos la query
    $sql->execute(); // se confirma que el query exista
    //Verificamos el resultado
    $count = $sql->rowCount();
    if($count){
        $data = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                       ....
```

Como logro hacer que los datos obtenidos del form se puedan comparar con la contraseña que genero el hash argen2i?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicado de manera sencilla, el string que resulta de tu operación de hashing con Argon2, sólamente puede ser replicado con la contraseña con la que se creó.

Para esto, usualmente las librerías criptográficas ofrecen una función para verificar que la contraseña que se ingresa es igual a la que ya está almacenada en tu base de datos.

En tu caso, necesitas la función `password_verify` ( Puedes revisar su documentación aquí: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php )

En tu caso, primero debes hacer una consulta a tu tabla de usuarios, y recuperar el `hash`, osea la contraseña encriptada con la que el usuario se registró.

```php
<?php

$sql = $objdatabase->prepare('SELECT id_usuario, clave FROM usuarios WHERE usuario =:usuario');
$sql->bindParam(':usuario', $_POST['usuario'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->execute();
$count = $sql->rowCount();
$data = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$resultado = password_verify($_POST['clave'], $data->clave);

if ($resultado) {
  echo 'La contraseña es correcta';
}
```

Comment: esto ya lo intente, y no me funciona

Comment: ¿Te manda algún error?

Comment: lo estoy realizando de la siguiente forma 
```
$sql->bindParam(':clave', password_verify($_POST['clave'], PASSWORD_ARGON2I), PDO::PARAM_STR);
```
y simplemente me sale que las contraseñas no coinciden

Comment: Intenta hacerlo como lo describo en la respuesta, puesto que `password_verify` regresa `true` o `false`, mas no el hash, así que esa consulta nunca va a funcionar.

Comment: y como se supone que lo haria funcionar con el pdo? ando perdido

Comment: Por la opcion que me estas ofreciendo me estas dando a entender que: junto a password_verify valide que la contraseña que me esta dando el usuario sea igual al hash que tengo registrado en mi bd, es cierto? o ese $hash que representa?

Comment: Si, en efecto, actualicé mi respuesta para darte un ejemplo

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, ya capte la idea y me ha funcionado perfectamente